# Java - creating Object without change the Original one

Tags: java

would it be possible to create new Object with the attributes from the Original Object without changing it ?

For example :

```
public void exampleTests() {
        Tree t = Trees.makeTree(new int[]{2, 3, 4, 4, 1});//creating tree
        assertTrue(t.contains(4)); //check if 4 is a node
        assertFalse(t.contains(6));//check if 6 is a node
        assertEquals(4, t.size()); //return size-nodes number (only different digits)

        Tree t2 = t.add(6).add(7).add(6); // obj 2 take obj 1 and add 6 and 7 to it
        assertFalse(t.contains(6)); // the first object should have no 6
        assertTrue(t2.contains(6)); // the second object should have 6
```

Trees class :

```
public  class Trees  {

    public  static Tree makeTree(int[] elements) {

        Tree tree = new Nodes();
        for (int i : elements) {
            tree.add(i);
        }
        return tree;
    }

}
```

Tree interface

```
public interface Tree {


    public  Tree add(int i);

    public boolean contains(int i);

    public int size();

    public String elementsAsString();
```

Node Class :

```
public class Node  {
    int i;
    Node left;
    Node right;

    public Node(int data) {
        this.i = data;
        left = null;
        right = null;
    }
}
```

Nodes class :

```
public class Nodes implements Tree {


    private    Node root;

    public Nodes() {
        this.root = null;
    }

    @Override
     public Nodes add(int i) {
        root = insertNode(root, new Node(i));
        return new Nodes();
    }

     private Node insertNode(Node currentParent, Node newNode) {

        if (currentParent == null) {
            return newNode;
        } else if (newNode.i > currentParent.i) {
            currentParent.right = insertNode(currentParent.right, newNode);
        } else if (newNode.i < currentParent.i) {
            currentParent.left = insertNode(currentParent.left, newNode);
        }
        return currentParent;
    }
```

what do we call this in Java terms ?

Comment: In your example you would need to create an `add` method which returns a new object (i.e., internally it takes care to create a new `Tree` instance with the values of `this`, adjusted by whatever the `add` method is supposed to do. The keyword here is "immutable datastructure".

Comment: @C-Otto thanks , i thought about returning new Tree in the add method , but it seems that it will add those to a different Tree

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would need to create a copy of the original object.

One way to do it is with a copy constructor :

```
public Tree (Tree other) {
    // copy all the properties of other to the new object
}
```

Then change

```
Tree t2 = t.add(6).add(7).add(6);
```

to

```
Tree t2 = new Tree(t).add(6).add(7).add(6);
```

Note that if the members of `Tree` include reference types (i.e. references to other objects), you must decide whether to create new copies of these objects too. If you copy just the references, you'll get a shallow copy of the original object, which could cause problems.

EDIT:

Since it appears `Tree` is an interface, you'll have to create a copy constructor in the class that implements it:

```
public Nodes (Tree other) {
    // copy all the properties of other to the new object
}
```

Then you can create the copy directly:

```
Tree t2 = new Nodes(t).add(6).add(7).add(6);
```

or via a factory method:

```
Tree t2 = Trees.makeTree(t).add(6).add(7).add(6);
```

where `makeTree` is:

```
public  static Tree makeTree(Tree source) {

    Tree tree = new Nodes(source);
    return tree;
}
```

Note that `public Nodes (Tree other)` is not exactly a copy constructor now - it's more general than a copy constructor, since it can accept any implementation of the `Tree` interface and create a new `Nodes` instance that contains the same data.

Comment: thanks for your answer , is there anyone else to do it without the word "new" also as it is in the example above ?

Comment: @james A new instance will have to be created somehow. You could make a static method, so that the call would look like `Trees.makeCopyOfTree(t)`, but that method would have to create a new Tree instance internally.

Comment: @james What exactly do you want me to see there? I see you added the implementation of `makeTree`. You can have a similar `makeTree` method that accepts a `Tree` instead of an `int[]`.

Answer (score 1):

You would implement Tree as **immutable** (meaning a once instantiated object can not be changed) and create a new instance in add:

```
public Tree add(int node) {
    // highly inefficient, assuming nodes are internally stored as an int array
    // allocate new array + 1 size
    int[] nodes = new int[this.nodes.length + 1];
    // copy this tree's nodes
    System.arraycopy(this.nodes, 0, nodes, 0, this.nodes.length);
    // add new node
    nodes[nodes.length - 1] = node;
    // return new tree instance
    return new Tree(nodes);
}
```

Comment: can i actually do it with interfaces ? Tree interface Nodes class implements the interface , and Node class which create a new Node add it to the Nodes

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? Do you mean an interface "Node" with an "add(Node node)" method and "Tree implements Node"?

Comment: ill edit my post adding everything i did so far, i did return new Tree which did not work